# rebind angular expressions by filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my filter has config that my change at any time,
i need to listen to `config.change` and rebind all the expressions using this filter.

for example: i have translate filter that return string from a object by key and language the user choose (in a `<select>`). when the user choose another language i need to rebind all the expressions that using the translate filter.

and the answer "set the `$stateful` on the filter to `true` and run `$rootScope.$apply();` when you need to rebind" is not accepted (performance, performance, performance..)!

Comment: What is the question?...and where is the code?

Comment: how can i rebind expressions by filter?